# docker-sync excludes are not excluded?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker sync in my current development projects and since a few days it sync slow - very slow. So i thought I should exlude the cache and log folders and did the following in my docker-sync.yml:

```
syncs:
  apache-sync: # tip: add -sync and you keep consistent names as a convention
    src: './src'
    sync_excludes: ['.git', 'var/cache', 'var/log']
```

Then I pressed cmd+c to stop my current docker sync instance and fired it up again with `docker-sync-stack start` but still the folders above are synced.

Do I need to do something else? Can I tell docker-sync to recreate the containers or should I do this with docker-compose and after recreating starting docker-sync again?

Thanks for a hint!

Comment: I didn't know about docker-sync. I'm curious, what is its advantage over docker-compose and volumes?

Comment: @Robert I was told, that is much faster than compose and it is quite fast, but since a few days I have these issues that it does not sync frequently.

Comment: Have you done `docker-sync-stack clean` after changing `docker-sync.yml`?

Comment: 2019 update: you must stop your containers (`docker-compose stop`), then `docker-sync stop` then `docker-sync clean` and finally `docker-sync start` to reload the new config defined in `docker-sync.yml`. If you don't `docker-sync clean` between the stop/start, it won't reload the config.